# Smartgit keeps forgetting Repositorys

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitlab, smartgit

We have a small Git-setup here at work. One Computer works as Git-Lab server and two other PC's are using SmartGit to clone Repositorys from the server. On all PC's, the OS is Ubuntu 12.04. 
The Problem: Whenever i cloned a repo from Gitlab, next time i boot there is no repository in smartgit. I have to clone it again. Can anybody tell me whats the problem? Also, we are just beginners with Git.

Regards,